# SharePoint 2013 Workflow using Visual Studio SP-List Items category in the tool box

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin

While creating SharePoint 2013 Workflow using Visual Studio I cannot find SP-List Items category in the tool box

I need GetCurrentItemGuid and LookupSPLIstItemProperty activity from SP-ListItem category in the tool box.  However I cannot find the category itself.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can use LookUpSPListiem or LookUpSpListitemId under SP-List Category

In get dynamicValues properties use GUID to find the ID.